# How to center marker on Mapbox GL JS map on click?

Tags: center, marker, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map with a dynamic amount of custom markers. For my UI to work properly, I need to center the marker/map when you click on the custom marker.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you're trying to achieve, and include your code, and where you're stuck.

Comment: @SteveBennett User clicks marker > Marker moves to the center of screen + opens up popup.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be the "right way" or most elegant but here's what I ended up doing...

```
//I have this run inside a loop that creates the markers.

//create marker element
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = "marker link";

//create the marker object and popup object
let tmpMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el);
let tmpPopUp = new mapboxgl.Popup() 
    .setHTML('your popup html goes here');

// I "stuffed" the marker object as a property on the elment ( so I can retrieve it later on click)
el.markerInstance = tmpMarker;

//set the coordinates, add the popup and add it to the map.
tmpMarker
    .setLngLat([data.coordinates.longitude, data.coordinates.latitude])
    .setPopup(tmpPopUp)
    .addTo(map);

// add a click listener to the "marker" element
el.addEventListener("click", e => {

    // here's where I can use the "markerInstance" I added earlier to then expose the getLngLat
    let coords = e.target.markerInstance.getLngLat();

    //tell the map to center on the marker coordinates
    map.flyTo({
        center: coords,
        speed: 0.2
    });
});
```

Comment: please is there a way I can jump-to/flyTo with dynamic coordinates, say for example a map with a search box, when I search for a location, my query hits the server, and I use the coordinates from the response of my query to flyTo the marker location, I am using react??

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox GL JS documentation has two examples:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/jump-to/

Answer (score 0):

used react-map-gl for my project.

Solved mine with this

```
  const mapRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      property.map(({ laty_decimal, longx_decimal }) =>
        mapRef.current?.setCenter({
          lat: laty_decimal,
          lng: longx_decimal,
        })
      );
    }
  }, [property]);
```

this way whenever the coordinates change it'll update,  hope it helps

[read more](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map)